# Swift 3 tab bar disable tab

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a tab bar with 5 tabs. we want to create a feature that we can enable/disable some tabs of tab bar programmatically so that user will not able to click on it.

We have used default tab bar controller and we are using swift 3. Does anyone have an idea how to manage this stuff?

I have tried many ways but it seems that it's not possible to restrict the user to click on the tab.

Please let me know if anyone has faced and solved this issue.

Comment: Did you try isEnabled property on tabbarItem?

Comment: tabBarItem.isEnabled = false would work!!

Comment: @SivajeeBattina yes i have tried but not working.

Comment: @luckyShubhra.. Its not working.!!

Comment: Can you please try userInteractionEnabled on that?

Answer (score 4):

```
let tabBarControllerItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items

if let tabArray = tabBarControllerItems {
    tabBarItem1 = tabArray[0]
    tabBarItem2 = tabArray[1]

    tabBarItem1.isEnabled = false
    tabBarItem2.isEnabled = false    
}
```

Just put the block of code above in the viewDidLoad() method for starters and don't forget to create the tabBarItem variables

Comment: try this 

let tabBar3 : UITabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Title", image: nil, tag: 2)
tabBar3.isEnabled = false

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your `viewWillAppear()` method :

```
if  let arrayOfTabBarItems = tabBarViewController.tabBar.items as! AnyObject as? NSArray,tabBarItem = arrayOfTabBarItems[2] as? UITabBarItem {
        tabBarItem.enabled = false
    }
```

**Note** :The above code will disable your third tab from clicking, to disable any other, just change the index in the `arrayOfTabBarItems`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 xcode 8.3.3**

I am making a demo App For your Problem. This is the code for firstViewController in TabBar ViewController.

```
class firstViewController: UIViewController ,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
}


func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController.isKind(of: secondViewController.self as AnyClass) {
      return true  
    } 
    if viewController.isKind(of: thirdViewController.self as AnyClass) {
      return false
    } 
  }
}
```

In That Demo SecondViewController is Click and open ViewController. But thirdViewController is not clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a customTabBarController class and put the bellow code on viewDidLoad().

```
if  let arrayOfTabBarItems = self.tabBar.items as AnyObject as? NSArray,let tabBarItem = arrayOfTabBarItems[3] as? UITabBarItem {
        tabBarItem.isEnabled = false
    }
```

so you can change arrayOfTabBarItems index based on your requirment.